# Mandatory class attribute for child class

Tags: php, oop

Suppose I have a class car ---

```
class Car{
  var $type;

  function func1(){
  }

  function func2(){
  }
}
```

Now classes who are extending this I want all of them to initiate $type. They must do something like --

```
class Taxi extends class Car{
  var $type = 'taxi';
}
```

How can I achieve that ? abstract class - abstract variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off all you have syntax errors, You can not declare properties with var,  you have syntax error in declaring class Taxi it should be

```
class Taxi extends Car{
  public $type;
}
```

I think you want to realize something like this.

```
abstract class AbstractCar
{
    public $type;

    public function __construct()
    {
       $this->type = static::TYPE;
    }
}

class Taxi extends AbstractCar
{
    //const TYPE = 'foobar';
}

$car = new Car; //Fatal Error: Undefined class constant 'TYPE' (uncomment const TYPE = 'foobar';)
echo $car->type;
```

Comment: I was exactly looking for this. Thanks :)

Comment: But anyways public $type = 'taxi'; is not giving me any error it is working fine

Comment: yes it should be empty, one second I will edit my answer.

Comment: There's no syntax errors - you *can* declare properties with `var`. But more importantly, if `Taxi` declares its own constructor, it will override the `AbstractCar` one and bypass the check.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to make a check within a `final` constructor:

```
abstract class Car {

    public $type;

    final public function __construct()
    {
        if ( ! isset($this->type)) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                sprintf('%s::$type is undefined', __CLASS__)
            );
        }
    }

}
```

That the class should be abstract is natural, because it obviously has to be extended, but otherwise isn't really necessary.

Comment: This will fail if child class have it's own constructor

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "fail" ... Yes, the child class *can't* have a constructor at all if it wants to work, but on the other hand - there's no other way to really force it to declare the property.